# How to access a dictionary inside a dictionary?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to figure out how to access the value inside two dictionaries via JavaScript.

The JSON output from the server is;

{"meta":{},"linked":{custom_fields":[{"id":"4","name":"Department"}],"custom_field_values":[{"id":"0001","value":"Marketing","links":{"custom_field":{"id":"4","type":"custom_fields"}}}]

I need to list Marketing as the department. I can't seem to access "links" to pull the id.

If I create `var linked = linked.custom_field_values;` I get a response.

{"id":"0001","value":"Marketing","links":{"custom_field":{"id":"4","type":"custom_fields"}}}

As soon as I try to `var cfl = linked.links.custom_field.id` it's saying links isn't defined. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in trying to create a variable for this?

Links is a dict with Custom_field right under as a dict with the values I need.

Wouldn't this print out the department correctly if everything works right?

```
if(cfl.id == 4){
console.log('Department is ' + linked.value);
}
```

Comment: The first block you've posted is invalid JSON, so we can't really help you with it. Please update the question with the actual server output (you can double-check it at http://jsonlint.com).

Comment: Is `custom_field_values` an array? If so you would have to write `var linked = linked.custom_field_values[0];` to get that object.

Comment: `link` does not have a property `links`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this is the actual JSON from the server.

Comment: @computerguyinhere: Well, that's the problem: The server code is broken. As I said, the JSON is (quite) invalid: https://jsonlint.com/?json=%7B%22meta%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22linked%22%3A%7Bcustom_fields%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%224%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Department%22%7D%5D%2C%22custom_field_values%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%220001%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22Marketing%22%2C%22links%22%3A%7B%22custom_field%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%224%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22custom_fields%22%7D%7D%7D%5D

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `custom_field_values` an array. You have to look at the first item in the array like so `var linked = linked.custom_field_values[0];`

Comment: Thanks for the responses. 

Can we take it one level deeper? I need to access "links" custom_field: id.

Yes, custom_field_values is an array.

Answer (score 0):

With a proper formatted object, you see, that you have an array inside. So you need to take an index for the array.

```js
    var object = {
        meta: {},
        linked: {
            custom_fields: [
                {
                    id: "4",
                    name: "Department"
                }
            ],
            custom_field_values: [
                {
                    id: "0001",
                    value: "Marketing",
                    links: {
                        custom_field: {
                            id: "4",
                            type: "custom_fields"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    };

console.log(object.linked.custom_fields[0].id);
console.log(object.linked.custom_field_values[0].id);
```